# Search Form with Ajax - How to display

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, search

I've a question about the method to make a ajax search request.
My form, the ajax call and the query is working, but i don't know, what's the best way to return the results.
I want to 'update' a existing table. What's the best and cleanest method to do this?

I don't want to recreate the whole table. But should i use JSON object or directly return the result with the html code.

Thanks for helping! I would appreciate it, when you also send example codes for your solution.

Greez Thandor

Comment: By coding, what have you tried? Show your code.

Comment: I return a variable with the hole code (with tr, td, the rows etc.) to create an new table, well this is working, but i think it isn't the cleanest and best way, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

this code is for auto complete search

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function autocompelete(value)
        {
        $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "autocomplete.php",
      data: { id: value }
    })
      .done(function( msg ) {

        $('#autocomplete').html(msg);
        $('#autocomplete').show();
      });

    }
    </script>
```

html

```
<div id="search-bar">
                <form action="youpage.php" method="POST">
                    <input type="submit" name="search" class="search-btn" value="" />
                    <input type="text" name="brand" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="autocompelete(this.value)" id="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Model Number, Brand, Company ..." />
                </form>
                <div style="display:none" id="autocomplete"></div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the Code, this is the next step i wanna do. But first i want to fill my table with the result of the search, not the search form. 
I think my question was not clearly defined... ^^

Comment: remove the just use auto complete  to ur data for search